# Remember me login feature using OAuth

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, persistent, remember-me

How do apps like Instagram, Snapchat implement social logins? How do they retain the logged in session? These apps do not require us to login using Facebook or Google every time. What is the mechanism involved in such social login can someone explain? I know OAuth but cannot connect the dots